# Command to store File on HDFS

Tags: linux, file, hadoop, hdfs

**Introduction**

A Hadoop NameNode and three DataNodes have been installed and are running. The next step is to provide a File to HDFS. The following commands have been executed:

```
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso
copyFromLocal: `.': No such file or directory
```

and

```
hadoop fs -put ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso
put: `.': No such file or directory
```

without succes.

**Question**

Which command needs to be issued in order to store a file on HDFS?

Comment: Did you format your namenode (`hdfs namenode –format`) ? Also, I personnaly copy files using `hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal myfile`

Comment: Yes the namenode has already been formatted. `hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso` results in `copyFromLocal: `.': No such file or directory` and `sudo hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso` results in `Error: JAVA_HOME is not set and could not be found.`. The JAVA_HOME error is remarkable as the hdfs-namenode is running fine.

Comment: Does `hadoop fs -copyFromLocal ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso /` works ? It may happen because it tries to write in `/user/yourUserName` which doesn't exist.

Comment: This command works. The ISO has been stored in the DataNodes now. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If no path is provided, hadoop will try to copy the file in your hdfs home directory. In other words, if you're logged as *utrecht*, it will try to copy ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso to `/user/utrecht`.

However, this folder doesn't exist from scratch (you can normally check the dfs via a web browser). 
To make your command work, you have two choices :

- copy it elsewhere (`/` works, but putting everything there may lead to complications in the future)
- create the directory you want with `hdfs dfs -mkdir /yourFolderPath`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. `hadoop fs -copyFromLocal ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso /` works. I will accept and upvote the answer.