# Command to provide file to HBase which is subsequently stored in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, command, hbase, hdfs

**Introduction**

Follow-up question to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062440/command-to-store-file-on-hdfs).

HBase has been connected to HDFS. Is it possible to provide a file to HBase which is subsequently stored in HDFS using a command.

According to [this documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062440/command-to-store-file-on-hdfs) there are several HBase shell commands. However these commands are restricted to e.g. creation, deletion of tables.

**Question**

Which command needs to be issued to provide a file to HBase which will be subsequently stored in HDFS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is not clear.  HBase is a key-value store.  To put data into HBase you must first create a table with a schema (really, just a list of column families).  After the table is created, you can load data into the table; the HBase command is 'put'.  Quoting from the HBase book:

"Create a table named test with a single column family named cf. Verify its creation by listing all tables and then insert some values.

> hbase(main):003:0> create 'test', 'cf'
>
> 0 row(s) in 1.2200 seconds
>
> hbase(main):003:0> list 'test'
>
> ..
>
> 1 row(s) in 0.0550 seconds
>
> hbase(main):004:0> put 'test', 'row1', 'cf:a', 'value1'
>
> 0 row(s) in 0.0560 seconds
>
> hbase(main):005:0> put 'test', 'row2', 'cf:b', 'value2'
>
> 0 row(s) in 0.0370 seconds
>
> hbase(main):006:0> put 'test', 'row3', 'cf:c', 'value3'
>
> 0 row(s) in 0.0450 seconds
>   "

If you want to load a large file row by row, you will have to either write a program, or google "Bulk loading"

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will read [this documentation](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/09/how-to-use-hbase-bulk-loading-and-why/) regarding "Bulk loading".